# Error during accessed localhost site access by another system

Tags: magento-1.9

I can't accessed my developing localhost site by another system.

I get error like,

**php error :**

> [08-Jul-2016 04:51:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ionCube Loader'
>    already loaded in Unknown on line 0

**Apache error :**

> [Fri Jul 08 09:55:47.696504 2016] [core:warn] [pid 3920:tid 264]
>    AH00098: pid file C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/logs/httpd.pid
>    overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run? [Fri Jul 08
>    09:55:47 2016] [warn-ioncube] The ionCube PHP Loader is disabled
>    because of startup problems. (pid 3920 th 3352) [Fri Jul 08
>    09:55:47.756504 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3920:tid 264] AH00455:
>    Apache/2.4.9 (Win32)

[image]

Comment: so you dont want to fix errors in the error log??

Comment: what is the error

Comment: first ioncube loaded twice, then 403 Forbidden error, maybe you have incorrect .htaccess or permission issues

Comment: okay, how can i solve this